# Why does magento generate two same cron jobs?

Tags: magento, cron

crontab: run cron.php every 5 minutes;

config.xml

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
            <newsletter_send_all>
                <schedule><cron_expr>20 2 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                    <run><model>psteal/observer_psteal::updatefrommagento</model></run>
            </newsletter_send_all> 
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

The generated data in DB ,TABLE is cron_schedule:

job_code                   status       messages    created_at      scheduled_at

newsletter_send_all     pending     NULL        2013-01-25 02:18:46     2013-01-25 02:20:00

newsletter_send_all     pending     NULL        2013-01-25 02:18:46     2013-01-25 02:27:00

I don't know why magento generates two same cron jobs?It should be only one job(at 2013-01-25 02:20:00) ,Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the cron task name from **newsletter_send_all** to **psteal_newsletter_send_all** for example, since newsletter_send_all is already defined in app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/etc/config.xml

Comment: I'd changed name from newsletter_send_all to psteal_newsletter_send_all ,still the same error;In fact, I just give an example like newsletter_send_all，Other task generates two same cron jobs also.I don't know why?

Comment: all tasks generate double tasks with a difference of 7 minutes?